# Java Regex pattern matching first occurrence of “boundary” after any character sequence

Tags: java, regex

I want to set a pattern which will find a capture group limited by the first occurrence of the “boundary”.  But now the last boundary is used.

E.g.:

```
String text = "this should match from A to the first B and not 2nd B, got that?";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\b(A.*B)\\b");
Matcher mtchr = ptrn.matcher(text);
while(mtchr.find()) {
    String match = mtchr.group();
    System.out.println("Match = <" + match + ">");
}
```

prints:

```
"Match = <A to the first B and not 2nd B>"
```

and I want it to print:

```
"Match = <A to the first B>"
```

What do I need to change within the pattern?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Make your `*` *non-greedy* / *reluctant* using `*?`:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\b(A.*?B)\\b");
```

By default, the pattern will behave greedily, and match as many characters as possible to satisfy the pattern, that is, up until the last *B*.

See *Reluctant Quantifiers* from [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), and [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Answer (score 6):

Don't use a greedy expression for matching, i.e.:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\b(A.*?B)\\b");
```

Answer (score 4):

`*` is greedy quantifier that matches as many characters as possible to satisfy the pattern. Up to the last `B` occurrence in your example. That is why you need to use reluctant one: `*?`, that will mach as few characters as possible. So, your pattern should be slightly changed:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\b(A.*?B)\\b");
```

See “reluctant quantifiers” in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), and [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

Comment: This is reworked [answer of **pb2q**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848600/java-regex-pattern-matching-first-occurence-of-boundry-after-any-character-seq#12848623) that wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more explicit than making the `*` reluctant/lazy would be to say that you're looking for A, followed by a bunch of stuff that *isn't a B*, followed by the B:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\b(A[^B]*B)\\b");
```