# java substring using regex not returning multiple

Tags: java, regex

I'm enclosing some data in between "%~". Like: %~abc%~

```
String regex = "%~(.+)%~";
String data = "Hello %~abc%~ pqr %~xyz%~";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

I'm getting output as: abc%~ pqr %~xyz

The regex pattern is matching the first %~ in %~abc the last %~ in xyz%~ and hence displaying all the content within them.

Whereas I want to match two times:

%~abc%~ => abc

%~pqr%~ => pqr

How can I get this output?

Comment: Or actually this could be better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12848600/java-regex-pattern-matching-first-occurrence-of-boundary-after-any-character-s. In short `*` is greedy quantifier, make it reluctant.

Comment: @Pshemo Didn't get you?

Comment: Your question is duplicate of another question (actually lot of questions have similar problem). Try reading answers in question from my previous comment. This should also help https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html